# How can I find all matches to a regular expression in android

Tags: java, android, regex

How can I find all matches to a regular expression in android. I founds it for Perl, Python etc but not for android.

Comment: Android uses Java, so Google this "regexp Java".

Comment: You have to use the ``java.util.regex`` package that comes with Android. The documentation is here: [Pattern Reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here's an example:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
...
// Find all the words of "foo bar".
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\w+").matcher("foo bar");
while (m.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found: " + m.group(0));
}
```