# Regex pattern starting with a String and ending with ')' with multiple occurances

Tags: regex, pattern-matching

Please suggest me the regex pattern:

String :

> this is text ) doing regex test. Error Caused by: faulty pattern (com.test.Validator.java:32) few more text Error Caused by: faulty pattern (com.test.Validator2.java:65) few more text

Need to extract:

> **Caused by: faulty pattern (com.test.Validator.java:32)**
>   and 
>   **Caused by: faulty pattern (com.test.Validator2.java:65)**

Regex pattern using:

> Caused by:(.*?)([^)])*

Issues:

1. Only giving me the first occurrence.
2. ')' getting excluded

Comment: #1 relates to the code which uses the regex as opposed to the regex itself - you'll need to show us that code for us to help with that (although, to make it useful to future visitors, it's probably best asked as separate questions, but I'm sure there's a duplicate of that somewhere, like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884484/how-can-i-find-all-matches-to-a-regular-expression-in-android)).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
Caused by:[^)]+\)
```

Note that you need the **`g`** modifier for multiple macthes.

[**Online demo**](https://regex101.com/r/bD4oD9/1)

In *Java*, you need an additonal backslash:

```
Caused by:[^)]+\\)
```

This regex matches `Caused by` followed by a positive number of characters (except `)`) followed by `)`.

Comment: Thanks....it works great. But how to get all the occurrences in a string? I am using Java

Comment: @saptarshi 
 
Do you want all matches in *one* string?

Comment: Thanks @Sven.....I have searched all other occurrences using Java....thanks for you help...

Comment: Need another help.....how to extract the string till ')' starting with 'Caused *:' excluding 'Caused *:'

Comment: @saptarshi You can try this regex: `(?<=Caused by: )[^)]+\\)`.

Answer (score 1):

For Java you can used next:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("Caused by: [^)]+\\)");
        Matcher m = p.matcher("Caused by: faulty pattern (com.test.Validator.java:32) and Caused by: faulty pattern (com.test.Validator2.java:65)");
        while(m.find()){
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Making the assumption than you always want to match to the first closing parenthesis.

```
Caused by:.*?\)
```