# Xamarin Android how to show list if user start typing with @ special character like whatsapp tagging features?

Tags: c#, android, regex, xamarin.android, android-edittext

I want to show the user list when the user starts typing with @ special character like tagging features in WhatsApp.

I use a regular expression but it works for only the first word not working for second words, like "Hello @abc and @xyz."

below is my code.

```
if (searchtext.ToString().Contains("@"))
{
   Regex regex = new Regex("@([a-zA-Z])+");
   MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(searchtext.ToString());
   if (matches != null && matches.Count != 0)
    {
       string temptext = matches[matches.Count - 1].ToString().Substring(1);
       searchUserList = userList.Where(s=>s.userName.ToLower().StartsWith(temptext.ToString().ToLower())).ToList();

       _usersListAdapter = new TagUsersListAdapter(this.Activity, searchUserList, this);
       _lstViewUsers.SetAdapter(_usersListAdapter);

       _lstViewUsers.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    }
    else
    {
        _lstViewUsers.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
    }

}
else
{
   _lstViewUsers.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;

   _usersListAdapter = new TagUsersListAdapter(this.Activity, userList, this);
   _lstViewUsers.SetAdapter(_usersListAdapter);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to your description, you want to search item from List and display ListView when user start type specific characters, I have made a sample that you can see:

Main_Activity.axml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:id="@+id/editText1"/>

 <ListView android:id="@+id/mainlistview" 
           android:layout_height="match_parent" 
           android:layout_width="match_parent" android:visibility="gone" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Mainactivity.cs:

```
 public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{


    private EditText edittext;
    List<person> items;
   private ListView mainList;
    private UsersListAdapter usersListAdapter;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        items = new List<person>()
        {
       new person(){username="cherry",age=12 },
       new person(){username="barry",age=23},
       new person(){username="wendy",age=13},
        new person(){username="wendy2",age=13},
         new person(){username="cherry3",age=12 },
       new person(){username="barry4",age=23}
        };

        mainList = (ListView)FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.mainlistview);
        //mainList.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, items);

        edittext = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
        mainList = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.mainlistview);
        edittext.TextChanged += Edittext_TextChanged;                     
    }

    private void Edittext_TextChanged(object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Text.ToString().Contains("@"))
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex("@([a-zA-Z])+");
            MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(e.Text.ToString());
            if (matches != null && matches.Count != 0)
            {
                int count = matches.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    string temptext = matches[i].ToString().Substring(1);

                    List<person> searchUserList = items.Where(s => s.username.ToLower().StartsWith(temptext.ToString().ToLower())).ToList();

                    mainList.Adapter = new UsersListAdapter(this, searchUserList);

                    mainList.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                mainList.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                mainList.Adapter = new UsersListAdapter(this, items);

            }

        }
    }

    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}

public class person
{
    public string username { get; set; }
    public int age { get; set; }
}
```

Adapter:

```
public class UsersListAdapter : BaseAdapter<person>
{
    List<person> items;
    Activity context;

    public UsersListAdapter(Activity context, List<person> items) : base()
    {
        this.context = context;

        this.items = items;
    }
    public override person this[int position]
    {
        get { return items[position]; }
    }

    public override int Count
    {
        get { return items.Count; }
    }


    public override long GetItemId(int position)
    {
        return position;
    }

    public override View GetView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
    {
        var item = items[position];



        View view = convertView;

        if (view == null) // no view to re-use, create new

        view = context.LayoutInflater.Inflate(Resource.Layout.layout2, null);

        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv1).Text = item.username;

        view.FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.tv2).Text = item.age.ToString();


        return view;
    }
}
```

Layout2.axml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

<TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/tv1"/>
 <TextView
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
    android:id="@+id/tv2" />

  </LinearLayout>
```

The sample in github:

https://github.com/CherryBu/searchTextSample

The Screenshot:

[image]

**Update:**

I update some code in MainActivity.cs, please take a look my code:

```
public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
{


    private EditText edittext;
    List<person> items;
   private ListView mainList;
    private UsersListAdapter usersListAdapter;
    private person selecteditem;
    private List<person> searchUserList;
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
        // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);

        items = new List<person>()
        {
       new person(){username="cherry",age=12 },
       new person(){username="barry",age=23},
       new person(){username="wendy",age=13},
        new person(){username="wendy2",age=13},
         new person(){username="cherry3",age=12 },
       new person(){username="barry4",age=23}
        };

        //mainList = (ListView)FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.mainlistview);
        //mainList.Adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, items);

        edittext = FindViewById<EditText>(Resource.Id.editText1);
        mainList = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.mainlistview);
        mainList.ItemClick += delegate (object sender, AdapterView.ItemClickEventArgs e)
        {
            if(searchUserList.Count>0)
            {
                selecteditem = searchUserList[e.Position];
                int index = edittext.Text.LastIndexOf("@");
                int count = edittext.Text.Length;

                edittext.Text = edittext.Text.Remove(index+1,count-index-1).Insert(index+1,selecteditem.username.ToString());
                //edittext.Text = edittext.Text + selecteditem.username.ToString();
                edittext.SetSelection(edittext.Text.Length);
                selecteditem = null;
                mainList.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            }

        };
        edittext.TextChanged += Edittext_TextChanged;                     
    }

    private void Edittext_TextChanged(object sender, Android.Text.TextChangedEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Text.ToString().Length > 2 && e.Text.ToString().Substring(e.Text.ToString().Length-2, 1) =="@")
        {
            Regex regex = new Regex("@([a-zA-Z])+");
            MatchCollection matches = regex.Matches(e.Text.ToString());
            if (matches != null && matches.Count != 0)
            {
                int count = matches.Count;
                for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
                {
                    string temptext = matches[i].ToString().Substring(1);

                     searchUserList = items.Where(s => s.username.ToLower().StartsWith(temptext.ToString().ToLower())).ToList();


                    mainList.Adapter = new UsersListAdapter(this, searchUserList);

                    mainList.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                mainList.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
                mainList.Adapter = new UsersListAdapter(this, items);

            }



        }
    }

    public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
    {
        Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

        base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
    }
}
```

The screenshot is here:

[image]

Here is the update sample, you can take a look:

https://github.com/CherryBu/searchtextsample2

Comment: Thanks, I will try.

Comment: @Adil, If my reply help you, please remember to mark my reply as answer,thanks.

Comment: hello @Cherry Bu - MSFT I Implement your code but I want to hide listview after if the user selects a name from first @ and then search data from second @ start. same as whats app chat tag user using @.

Comment: @AdilSaiyad, please see my update, if my reply help you, please remember to mark my reply as answer, thanks.

Comment: Github link is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I think your regex should be `@([a-zA-Z]+)`.

Demo: https://regex101.com/r/r676aK/1

This demo is based on Python and using the global flag to not stop at the first match. But, for getting all matches on Android Java, you might refer to [How can I find all matches to a regular expression in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6884484/how-can-i-find-all-matches-to-a-regular-expression-in-android) (note that the answer is from 2011).